# Memory leak - probably 'cause of to many eventhandlers

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, memory-leaks

I think i found a memory-leak in my desktop application (.NET 4.0, WinForms, VB.NET). Unfortunately i can't explain, why it occurs.

I have a `Form` with a custom-`TabControl` (inherited from `XtraTabControl` - DevExpress). This `TabControl` shows in every `TabPage` a different set of customers. If you doubleclick on a row (a customer), i open a new `Form` with all the details of the customer. In this new `Form` there are a few `DataGrids` (again a custom control using the `GridControl` and `GridView` from DevExpress) and a lot of other controls (`Labels`, `TextBoxes`, etc.). If the detail-`Form` is already open, it gets updated with the new customers data.

Here are some facts for the memory leak:

- after starting the app: 77 Mb RAM used; 2.640 `EventHandlers` holding 90 Kb RAM
- after opening 25 customers: 190 Mb used; 75.016 `EventHandlers` holding  127 Mb RAM
- after closing the two forms: still 190 Mb used, 66.216 `EventHandlers` holding 132 Mb RAM

I tried `System.GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced)` just for fun (i know i shouldn't do that), but it doesn't changed anything at all.

I know that the publisher of an event holds a reference to the subscriber, so if the publisher lives longer than the subscriber, then it will keep the subscriber alive. BUT if i close all two `Forms`, shouldn't be then all good?

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the memory, after opening 25 customers and closing the 2 forms. It looks like, there are still a lot of controls in the memory :(
[image]
(columns translated: Object type | count | size | holding memory size)

EDIT 2: Here's another screenshot of ANTS Memory Profiler. Unfortunately i can't get the clue out of it:
[image]

Hope u guys can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: This might not be a "memory leak". Leave your application open for 10 minutes to see if the RAM reduces. Thoughts to have a look at - try `Disposing` forms after they are closed. Also if you are calling `AddHandler` to programmatically add event handlers you should call `RemoveHandler` somewhere.

Comment: I try that. Thought i can simulate that with `System.GC.Collect()` so i don't have to wait. The two forms get disposed. Also i checked, if all the children-controls get disposed too - that works well (Dispose-Code from the designer).

Comment: Get memory profiler like JetBrains dotMemory or any other and check if your objects are still in memory after closing the form

Comment: I add a screenshot after opening 25 customers and closing the 2 forms. Still a lot of controls in memory. But why? After closing the 2 forms there shouldn't be any references on any controls (or am i misunderstanding anything)?

Comment: @roli09 I'm not familiar with this profiler, can it show the path from root to the leaked object? Look at it and most likely you will realize why it is still in memory.

Comment: @Ed.ward this is the profiler of Visual Studio 2015. I don't know if i can show the path, but i just downloaded ANTS Memory Profiler and with that it is possible. I will add another screenshot to the question. Hope u can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I think i got it!

I installed .NET Memory Profiler 5.0 and this application showed me the callstack of the `event` which was holding the `GridViews`. Then I implemented some `Dispose`-methods in my custom controls and currently i'm getting back almost all of my memory.

BTW: Is it a bad design to remove `EventHandlers` in the `Dispose`-Method?

Comment: What do you mean by removing `EventHandlers` in the `Dispose`? Unsubscribing?

Comment: Yes, i meant unsubscribing.

Comment: `Dispose` is an absolutely right place for unsubscribing from any events. Disposing means end of logical lifetime of an object, GC will collect it later, but from the point of view of the application disposed object is dead object.